# How do I Add Text to an existing Field using NestJs with Angular and MongoDB?

Tags: angular, typescript, mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

I'm coding a Ticketsystem right now, and now im at this point where I have a page to Display the Ticket and I need to add the opportunity to answer the Ticket over and over again. I am able to edit a Ticket with a put() but then im Overwriting the old Content. So I need a way to add new Text without deleting the older one.
Edit: There are 2 Users, TicketCreator and then someone who answers.

Im using Angular, NestJS and MongoDB (via TypeORM)

Im going to provide my ticketdetail.component.html & ticketdetail.component.ts (from Angular) and my ticket.service.ts & ticket.controller.ts to show you what I got.

```
ticketdetail.component.html:

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <h2>
        <span class="badge badge-flenders">Ticket von {{ data.creator }} </span>
      </h2>
      <p *ngIf="data.state === 'ungelesen'" class="badge badge-danger">
        {{ data.id }}
      </p>
      <p *ngIf="data.state != 'ungelesen'" class="badge badge-success">
        {{ data.id }}
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="boxed">
      <span> {{ data.content }} </span>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-4 mt-0.5">Antworten</button>
  </div>
</div> 


ticketdetail.component.ts:
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ticketDto } from 'src/app/services/dtos/ticket.dto';
import { userDto } from 'src/app/services/dtos/user.dto';
import { TicketService } from 'src/app/services/ticketService.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ticketdetail',
  templateUrl: './ticketdetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ticketdetail.component.scss'],
})
export class TicketdetailComponent implements OnInit {
  ticketId: any;
  data!: ticketDto;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private ticketService: TicketService
  ) {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: { [x: string]: any }) => {
      this.ticketId = params['id'];
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ticketService
      .getTicketById(this.ticketId)
      .subscribe((ticket: ticketDto) => {
        this.data = ticket;
      });
  }
}



ticket.service.ts:
import {
  BadRequestException,
  Injectable,
  NotFoundException,
  Param,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import { CreateTicketDto } from '../dto/create-ticket.dto';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Db, getConnection, ObjectID, Repository, UpdateResult } from 'typeorm';
import { TicketEntity } from '../entities/ticket.entity';
import { Iticket } from '../interfaces/ticket.interface';
import { MongoRepository } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class TicketService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(TicketEntity)
    private readonly ticketRepository: MongoRepository<TicketEntity>,
  ) {}

  async createTicket(_ticket: Iticket): Promise<any> {
    return this.ticketRepository.save(_ticket);
  }

  async findAll(): Promise<TicketEntity[]> {
    return this.ticketRepository.find();
  }

  async findByCreator(ticketcreator: string): Promise<TicketEntity> {
    console.log(ticketcreator);
    return this.ticketRepository.findOne(ticketcreator);
  }

  async findById(id: string): Promise<TicketEntity> {
    console.log(id);
    return await this.ticketRepository.findOne(id);
  }

  updateTicket(id: ObjectID, ticket: Iticket): Observable<UpdateResult> {
    return from(this.ticketRepository.update(id, ticket));
  }

  async deleteTicket(_id: ObjectID): Promise<string> {
    const exists =
      /* ObjectID.isValid(_id) &&  */ await this.ticketRepository.findOne(_id);
    if (!exists) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    const _result = await this.ticketRepository.delete(_id);
    if (_result.affected == 1) {
      return 'Erfolgreich gelöscht';
    } else {
      throw new BadRequestException();
    }
  }

  async update(content: any): Promise<any> {
    return await this.ticketRepository.update(content, content);
  }
}

ticket.controller.ts:
import {
  Body,
  Controller,
  Delete,
  Get,
  Logger,
  Param,
  Post,
  Put,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { TicketService } from '../services/ticket.service';
import { NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common/exceptions/not-found.exception';
import { TicketEntity } from '../entities/ticket.entity';
import { lastValueFrom, firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { CreateTicketDto } from '../dto/create-ticket.dto';
import { ApiOperation, ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { ObjectID, UpdateDateColumn, UpdateResult } from 'typeorm';
import { Iticket } from '../interfaces/ticket.interface';

@Controller('tickets')
export class TicketController {
  constructor(private readonly ticketService: TicketService) {}

  @ApiOperation({
    summary: 'Erstellen eines neuen Tickets.',
  })
  @Post(':create')
  createTicket(@Body() ticket: CreateTicketDto): Promise<any> {
    return this.ticketService.createTicket(ticket);
  }

  @ApiOperation({
    summary: 'Bearbeiten eines Tickets.',
  })
  @Post(':id')
  async insertTicket() {}

  @ApiOperation({
    summary: 'Auflistung aller vorhandenen Tickets',
  })
  @Get()
  async findAll(): Promise<TicketEntity[]> {
    return this.ticketService.findAll();
  }
  @ApiOperation({
    summary: 'Anzeige eines bestimmten Tickets anhand des Erstellers.',
  })
  @Get('/:id')
  async findOne(@Param('id') id: string) {
    let _ticket = await this.ticketService.findById(id);
    console.log(_ticket);
    if (!_ticket) {
      throw new NotFoundException('Error.');
    }
    return _ticket;
  }
  /*async findByCreator(ticketcreator: string): Promise<TicketEntity> {
    return this.ticketService.findByCreator(ticketcreator);
  } */

  @Delete(':id')
  async del(@Param('id') id: ObjectID) {
    return this.ticketService.deleteTicket(id);
  }

  @Put(':id')
  update(
    @Param('id') id: ObjectID,
    @Body() ticket: Iticket,
  ): Observable<UpdateResult> {
    return this.ticketService.updateTicket(id, ticket);
  }
}
```